# Is there a way to make a summary table for a many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, query-optimization

We have a database table that has way too many rows.  to speed up performance, we are trying to create a summary table.  this works great for one to one relationships. e.g. let's say `furniture` has a `type` and a `manufacturer_id`, you could have a table that has both of these columns and a `counts` column.  it would be easy to query that table and very quickly get the number of furnitures of a given type.

But, what if there is a many to many relationship? so each piece of furniture can also have one or many `colors` and one or many `distributors`.  what happens then?  is there any way to summarize this data so i can quickly find how many furnitures are green?  or how many are blue and yellow?

obviously this is just a made up example.  but given a *huge* database table with millions and millions of rows, how can i create a summary table to quickly look up aggregate information?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what you do and know this is a real bottleneck: Do you have measurements of the performance now? Do you know where it starts taking time?

You will have to query the database anyway to get that count. So you can store it in a separate table like color count and distributor count. Another solution is to cache the results of these queries in a caching system. For example if you have memcached or some other tools already in use.

Most simply when you just have a database is just to create a table:

```
table color count
color_id
amount
```

That is a very simple query. You can index it very well and no joins are needed.

Updating can be done with triggers, with a cron or at the moment you update the many to many table. Depending on your needs and capacity. Take into consideration that updating the records also takes time so use it for optimizing reads, that's what I read in your question.

Comment: the color count table would work perfectly in a one-to-one scenario (we actually do that already).  but how does it work for many to many?  how would i be able to find the furniture that is both blue and yellow?

Comment: If you need to look for the real records, so not for the amount of furniture which has both blue and yellow then you will have to join the original records. If you just need the count you can store it for example in just 2 fields: color1_id color2_id. Then you order the color codes, smallest first. So you can search for: SELECT amount FROM colorcount WHERE color1_id=222 AND color2_id=333. No need for joining, grouping or whatever. But first, think about what's really necessary before setting this up.

Comment: but this is a *many to many* relationship. a piece of furniture has many colors.  if i wanted to check how mnay pieces of furniture wer green, red,blue, and yellow.. then what... i need 4 color cols?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tables should keep the size down... and a good database system should keep the performance up.

In my opinion, keeping a separate 'summary table' creates a lot of overhead and maintenance problems and is only really useful if the same summary information is desired over and over (i.e., how many furnitures are green without also storing how many are blue, how many are yellow, how many are blue and yellow, etc., etc., etc.)

What I would do is:

Table 1: furnitures

- Column 1: uniqueID
- Column 2: name

Table 2: distributors

- Column 1: uniqueID
- Column 2: name

Table 3: colors

- Column 1: uniqueID
- Column 2: name

Table 4: furniture-distributor

- Column 1: furnitureUniqueIDvalue
- Column 2: distributorUniqueIDvalue

Table 5: furniture-color

- Column 1: furnitureUniqueIDvalue
- Column 2: colorUniqueIDvalue

How many furnitures are green:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM furniture-color WHERE colorUniqueIDvalue = 'green ID';

How many furniture are both blue and yellow:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM furniture-color as t1 INNER JOIN furniture-color as t2 ON t1.furnitureUniqueIDvalue = t2.furnitureUniqueIDvalue AND t1.colorUniqueIDvalue = 'blue ID' AND t2.colorUniqueIDvalue = 'yellow ID';

Getting lists of distributors of blue and yellow furniture, or furniture from a particular distributor that is either green or red, or most anything else is possible with the right SQL statement (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: so what happens if my theoretical furniture business has 200 million pieces of furniture?  then both furniture-distributor and furniture-color would be even larger than 200 million rows and trying to query which furniture is from distributor 'ikea' and both 'red' and 'yellow' would take forever (or longer).  hence the reason for summary tables... to be able to quickly query aggregate data.

Comment: Generating summary tables may be the solution you need then but keep in mind you have the overhead of creating and maintaining them and you will have to guess in advance every possible combination of your many-to-many relationships. I will also point out that the furniture-distributor and furniture-color tables have only two fields each. Even if you had a billion records the disk space required would still be less than the space to hold the digital pictures I took at the air show last weekend.

Comment: It's not the disk space that i am worrying about.. it's querying a table that has a billion records

Comment: A binary search of a billion records is still just 30 compares. With modern database management systems indexing and hashing, the querying should not take more than a few milliseconds. If being done very  frequently, then caching the result would eliminate all but the first query with imposing the limits of pre-conceived summary tables designed to handle many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between counting different types of furniture (distinct furniture id) and counting actual pieces of furniture.

If you have a distributor-color table, then you can count actual pieces of furniture.  However, you cannot count different types of furniture.  This is the difference between additive facts and non-additive facts, in the terminology of OLAP.  If you are interested in this subject, check out Ralph Kimball and his classic book "The Data Warehouse Toolkit".

To count furniture types, you need to include that in your table.  So, you need a distributor-color-furniture table.  Now to get the total for a distributor, you can use:

```
select distributor, count(distinct furnitureid)
from dcf
group by distributor
```

And similarly for color.

It seems that you want to translate your original data into a fact table, for each of reporting.  This is a very good and standard idea for developing data marts.  Your data mart could have two fact tables.  One for each type of furniture (so you can handle the manufacturing questions easily) and other for distributor-color-furniture (for harder questions).

Some databases, such as Oracle and SQL Server, have support for these types of data structures.  What you are talking about is more like a new "system", rather than just a new "table".  You need to think about the dimensions for the fact table, the updates, and the types of reports that you need.

Answer (score 0):

There will be **2^n** possible rows in the color summary table where 'n' is the number of colors. If you reduce the colors to a bitmap and assign each color a location (red=0,orange=1,yellow=2,green=3,etc.) then your color summary table could be:

```
Color    Count
0x0001   256
0x0002   345
0x0003   23839
etc.
```

256 only have red, 345 only have orange, 23,839 have red and orange. To get a count of how many have red but could have other colors would require summing the rows with bit position 0 set. Alternatively a separate summary table could be set up with only 'n' entries, one for each color, to avoid summing over the rows.

If you want the summary table to manage both distributor and color then I think it would have **2^n * 2^m** rows (where 'm' is the number of distributors) to have all the combinations of multiple distributors for multiple pieces of furniture each possibly with multiple colors.